# Finding Big-O with multiple nested loops?

Tags: loops, nested, big-o

```
int num = n/4;
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
            int count = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

According to the books I have read, this code should be O((n^3)/4). But apparently its not. to find the Big-O for nested loops are you supposed to multiply the bounds? So this one should be num *n *n or n/4 *n *n.

Comment: A smart compiler would probably optimize this loop nest to be O(1), since it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: A "smart" compiler would leave it alone unless told otherwise - it may be a timing loop in an embedded system controlling blood flow rate through a dialysis machine:-)

Comment: There are much better ways to implement timing (in just about any language) than to create meaningless loops that will never have a defined execution time!

Answer (score 16):

`O((n^3)/4)` makes no sense in terms of big-O notation since it's meant to measure the complexity as a ratio of the argument. Dividing by 4 has no effect since that changes the value of the ratio but not its nature.

All of these are equivalent:

```
O(n^3)
O(n^3/4)
O(n^3*1e6)
```

Other terms only make sense when they include an `n` term, such as:

```
O(n^3 / log(n))
O(n^3 * 10^n)
```

As Anthony Kanago rightly points out, it's convention to:

- only keep the term with the highest growth rate for sums: `O(n^2+n) = O(n^2)`.
- get rid of constants for products: `O(n^2/4) = O(n^2)`.

As an aside, I don't always agree with that first rule in all cases. It's a good rule for deciding the maximal growth rate of a function but, for things like algorithm comparison<sup>(a)</sup> where you can intelligently put a limit on the input parameter, something like `O(n^4+n^3+n^2+n)` is markedly worse than just `O(n^4)`.

In that case, *any* term that depends on the input parameter should be included. In fact, even constant terms may be useful there. Compare for example `O(n+1e100)` against `O(n^2)` - the latter will outperform the former for quite a while, until `n` becomes large enough to have an effect on the constatnt term.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There are, of course, those who would say it shouldn't be used in such a way but pragmatism often overcomes dogmatism in the real world :-)

Comment: Also, n^3 + n includes that `+ n` as a lower-order term which can be dropped.

Comment: Thanks, @Anthony, I was just throwing together some samples, I should have read them a little more carefully before posting.

Comment: This is true only if your last name is not "Knuth"

Comment: It doesn't really make no sense, its just not following the convention regarding simplification.

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation you can see that constants like the 1/4 do not play a role for determining the Big-O notation. The only interesting fact is that it is n^3, thus O(N^3).

Answer (score 0):

Formally, the time complexity can be deduced like the following:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A small technicality.  Big O notation is intended to describe complexity in terms of the 'size' of the input, not the numeric value.  If your input is a number, then the size of the input is the number of digits of your number.  Alas, your algorithm is O(2^N^3) with N being the number of digits.

[More on this topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time)

Comment: You've lost me here, @token. The "size" in this loop is clearly the numerical value, not the number of digits (which would require a log-base-10 on n somewhere).